# Is it possible to instantiate and call a method of the class my Analyzer is analyzing right now?

Tags: c#, roslyn, analyzer, roslyn-code-analysis

My analyzer will match methods with certain signatures. I would like from inside my analyzer to create an instance of the class I'm analyzing and call the method that caused the analyzer to kick in.

Assuming the source code is in a compilable state, is it possible?

Getting the class name and method name is pretty easy, but Type.GetType(...) will always return null.

The purpose of this is that I would like for my analyzer to kick in when I'm on a test method and run it, failing if the test fails.

If the code is not ready for compilation, it would be fine to just return.

Comment: No; it hasn't been compiled (and the project may in fact have build errors), and certainly hasn't been loaded into VS (and it must not be).  You can't do that.

Comment: What is the point of running tests from an analyzer? Why not use a test execution framework such as the standard test runner from VS, xUnit test runners, or NUnit ones. They integrate perfectly with VS. You can even extend their behavior through different extension points.

Comment: Because that's manual work. I'm looking for something like ncrunch, but simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems possible, but you'd need to check the efficiency of these solutions. Also, you can't guarantee that the code is compilable.

You can grab the `Compilation` object (from let's say `context.SemanticModel.Compilation`), call `Emit` on it, and write it to disc. Then use `Assembly.Load` to load it, and then it's simple reflection to instantiate the class, whose name you already know, and call the method on it with appropriate arguments.

Another approach would be to use the `Compilation` in a scripting session as a reference assembly, and use the Roslyn Scripting API to invoke the method. There is a `ToMetadataReference` method on the `Compilation`, so you could get a `MetadataReference`, which could be then passed to `ScriptOptions.Default.AddReferences`. And then you'd need to pass the resulting options instance to `CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync()`.

Comment: Tks @Tamas, calling Emit fails with many reference errors. Compiler.ReferencedAssemblyNames shows only mscorlib, System.Core, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp and Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, but the project references many others. It also shows "error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point" although it's a class library. Any thoughts?

Comment: I just tried `c.SemanticModel.Compilation.Emit("output.dll")` on a minimal library project from a `RegisterSyntaxNodeAction` callback, and it works. Are you sure that you're building a class library? You can create a new compilation and specify that it has to be a DLL. for this, check out the `Compilation.WithOptions()`.

Comment: As for the reference errors, you might need to look into the `Compilation.References` and find a way to produce the referenced assemblies first. But I think this would go further then a simple proof-of-concept solution, so you should also consider what others have already mentioned that you might not at all be able to load the assembly if it targets different platforms. So this would make the applicability of your analyzer quite limited. What is the whole purpose of this? Maybe there are better ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: Did you try adding external references? I could make it using MSBuildWorkspace: from the source file, find the project, the solution, references, compile everything and run, but I was trying to find a shorter way. I updated my question adding the purpose.

Comment: I haven't tried adding other than framework references.

Comment: Hi @Tamas, I rewritten everything from scratch. That time the external assemblies were loaded and the Emit returned success. I probably did something wrong somewhere with so many changes. Now it's the easy part. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There's another fundamental reason you can't run code from the user's compilation, even if it did actually compile -- it might be the wrong environment. Consider a scenario where you're targeting Windows Phone, or Xamarin Android/iOS, .NET Core on Linux, or whatever. In any of these cases the compiler has reference assemblies that you can compile *against* but obviously you can't actually run that code because it's targeting a different platform. People often ask why you can't convert an ITypeSymbol to a reflection System.Type and back, and this is one of the reasons why -- the compiler can compile code on platform A for platform B, when it can't actually run (or fully load) B's assemblies in the first place.